# C# equivalent of C++ deferred async execution?

Tags: c#, c++, asynchronous

I'm relatively new to C# and I'm trying to replicate an asynchronous call that has already been written in C++. This has been a little difficult because while I can easily understand the async/await keywords in C#, I'm stuck on the concept of deferred launch in that language. Here is the original code:

```
bool runMethod(const cv::Mat& param1,
             float& param2,
             std::pair<float, float>& param3,
             std::pair<int, int>& param4)
{
   auto async_lazy{ std::async(std::launch::deferred,
    [&param1, &param2, &param3, &param4]
    {
        const MyClass ret{ MyClass::getInstance()->Method(param1};

        if (ret.status)
        {
            //Do work...
        }

        return ret.status;
    }) };

    return async_lazy.get();
}
```

It may be relevant to add that the "Method" method being called is not async itself.

I also took a look at the first example on this page, that says a Task<(T)> by itself is async. There also seems to be no use of the await keyword:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1?view=net-6.0

Would that example reproduce the functionality of the above code?

Comment: It isn't usually a good idea to try and take C++ source code and attempt to mimic what it does with another computer language you are not familiar with.  That goes in general -- to properly translate from language A to language B, you need to know both A and B well enough to 1) Understand what A is doing, and 2) Throw away language A and implement the same solution in language B using language B's idioms.

Comment: The [All your base are belong to us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us) scenario is a reminder of bad translations.  You don't want to wind up in that situation.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is true in an ideal world, where a programmer could call the shots. Boss wants me to translate this for future maintainability due to lack of C++ programmers we have. I'm working with the only two languages I know.

Comment: Doesn't look like that's asynchronous at all. It seems to be creating a lazy-evaluated value (represented by a promise), and then immediately getting the result of that promise (thus lazy-evaluating the value). AFAICT the C++ code is pure overhead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If my quick google search was correct then `launch::deferred` means lazy evaluation on the calling thread.

In that case, using a task might not be a good idea, they are not meant for lazy evaluation because:

- Awaiting them or taking their result does not start them if they were
  not started already (and starting them while they are already running throws an exception)
- You can't run them on the calling thread, they represent an asynchronous operation (such as IO) or work running on a ThreadPool thread
- Even if you could run them on the calling thread if they were not started yet, they are typically created using `Task.Run()` or `Task.Factory.StartNew()` which starts them right away

Perhaps you could use `System.Lazy<T>` instead. It seems to do what you need, including several thread safety options.